# Simulation of FIFO Generator 13.2 (with AXI Stream Interface)

Tags: vhdl, fpga, fifo, vivado

Hello I need your help!

I want to simulate only FIFO Generator 13.2 (with AXI-Stream).
When I simulate this IP-Core, the simulation is not working properly.

https://hizliresim.com/UmVAzT

How can I simulate this IP-Core without connect anywhere. I hace an homework for this pls help me

You can see the testbench, I need your help with this homework pls.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb_fifo_axi is
end tb_fifo_axi;

architecture tb of tb_fifo_axi is

component fifo_axi
    port (wr_rst_busy   : out std_logic;
          rd_rst_busy   : out std_logic;
          s_aclk        : in std_logic;
          s_aresetn     : in std_logic;
          s_axis_tvalid : in std_logic;
          s_axis_tready : out std_logic;
          s_axis_tdata  : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
          s_axis_tuser  : in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
          m_axis_tvalid : out std_logic;
          m_axis_tready : in std_logic;
          m_axis_tdata  : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
          m_axis_tuser  : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0));
end component;

signal wr_rst_busy   : std_logic;
signal rd_rst_busy   : std_logic;
signal s_aclk        : std_logic;
signal s_aresetn     : std_logic;
signal s_axis_tvalid : std_logic;
signal s_axis_tready : std_logic;
signal s_axis_tdata  : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
signal s_axis_tuser  : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal m_axis_tvalid : std_logic;
signal m_axis_tready : std_logic;
signal m_axis_tdata  : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
signal m_axis_tuser  : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
constant clk_period : time := 50 ns;


begin

dut : fifo_axi
port map (wr_rst_busy   => wr_rst_busy,
          rd_rst_busy   => rd_rst_busy,
          s_aclk        => s_aclk,
          s_aresetn     => s_aresetn,
          s_axis_tvalid => s_axis_tvalid,
          s_axis_tready => s_axis_tready,
          s_axis_tdata  => s_axis_tdata,
          s_axis_tuser  => s_axis_tuser,
          m_axis_tvalid => m_axis_tvalid,
          m_axis_tready => m_axis_tready,
          m_axis_tdata  => m_axis_tdata,
          m_axis_tuser  => m_axis_tuser);


  clk_process :process
  begin
    s_aclk <= '0';
    wait for clk_period/2;
   s_aclk <= '1';
    wait for clk_period/2;
 end process;

stimuli : process
begin
    
   
    s_axis_tvalid <= '0';
    s_axis_tready <= '0';
    s_axis_tuser <= (others => '0');
    m_axis_tready <= '0';
    m_axis_tvalid <= '0';
    
    s_aresetn <= '0';
    
    wait for 20 ns;
    s_axis_tdata <= "01010101";
    s_axis_tvalid <= '1';
    s_axis_tready <= '1';
    s_aresetn <= '1';
    m_axis_tready <= '1';
    m_axis_tvalid <= '1';
    wait for 20 ns;
    m_axis_tdata <=s_axis_tdata;
   
   
    
    wait;
end process;

end tb;
```

Comment: This is where you learn debugging. Trace back from the incorrect signals, or trace forward from the correct ones to see where they go wrong. Then fix that, and repeat...

Comment: You need to run your tests based on Clock.   So rather than `wait for 20 ns` you need to do `wait until rising_edge(Clk)`.   The notation of `m_` and `s_` is very confusing here as what is `m` in the DUT is `s` in the testbench.   From a structure standpoint, I would have one process that drives AXI data to the FIFO and a separate process the receives AXI data from the FIFO.

Comment: Next in the process that drives AXI data to the FIFO, I would create a procedure, named send, that sends information to the FIFO.    In the process the receives AXI data from the FIFO, I would create a procedure named get that receives information from the FIFO

Comment: The next step would be to use AXI stream verification components.   You can learn more about this here:   https://github.com/OSVVM/Documentation/blob/master/AxiStream_user_guide.pdf